# Python: Find when figure window has been moved

Tags: python, matplotlib, canvas, figure

Good evening. I should define the x and y coordinates of the figure window when i move it. There is a way to know when a window has been moved/dragged across the screen in python?

I use the method `fig.canvas.manager.window.winfo_geometry()` to get the x and y coordinates but how do I get a callback when I move the window?

thanks.

Comment: Could you please share some code, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: You might be looking for [this solution](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-window-size.htm)?!